# Synology NAS not accessible via hostname in Domain, IP Address works

Tags: networking, dns, nas, synology, windows-server-2016

We have a Synology NAS DS918+ running the latest DSM (DSM 6.2.1-23824).

The Synology is linked to our Domain, and  has the following networking settings:

Hostname: SRVSTORAGE / IP Static (192.168.1.115)

We use group policies to map certain drives, folder redirection and have roaming profiles enabled.

Last week there was a power failure and the Synology has had a cold shutdown. Since then we can't access the NAS by using the hostname (e.g. \srvstorage\general). He always prompts for login credentials, and accepts no Domain logon information.

If we access the ip address directly (e.g. 192.168.1.115\general) everything works fine, and he accepts the Domain auth).

There has been no other changes on the Windows Server 2016.

Did anyone experience something similar? And has a solution been found.

Thanks
K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was fixed by letting the Synology NAS sync with an NTP server.

Kindest regards
Kiran